# Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T: M_{2\times 2} \longrightarrow M_{3\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T: M_{2\times 2} \longrightarrow M_{3\times 2}$
> with $T(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}a+b&2d\\2b-d&-3c\\2b-c&-3a\end{bmatrix}$ (with respect to standard basis).

I'm unsure how to solve this problem.

Normally I would apply $T$ to each of the standard basis vectors:

$T(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&-3\end{bmatrix}$

$T(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&0\\2&0\end{bmatrix}$

$T(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-3\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$

$T(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\-1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

And then form a matrix for $T$ where each column is one of the vectors above, but the matrix of $T$ in this case must be 3 x 2, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The matrix of T should be $6 \times 4$ here. If you know a basis for $M_{2\times2}$ and $M_{3\times2}$ then just plug in the coordinates inside your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expressing a linear transformation as a matrix with respect to some basis (and also when expressing vectors in a space as column vectors with respect to some basis), the actual form of the vectors in the space doesn't matter.

The matrix representation only cares about the coefficients in front of the chosen basis vectors, and that's it. Whether your vectors are points in space, or tables of numbers like here, or functions or whatever else, that is abstracted away once you choose a basis and start using that basis to express your vectors. We work only with the coefficients that that choice of basis vectors yield, the actual basis vectors do not really appear.

Assuming some standard basis on $M_{2\times 2}$ and $M_{3\times 2}$, we get that applying the linear transformation to the first basis vector of $M_{2\times 2}$ yields the first basis vector of $M_{3\times 2}$, minus three times the last basis vector. You say
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&-3\end{bmatrix}
$$
And this is how we see it when operating on the bare vectors of the space. However, when operating on the coordinates given to us by the basis choice, it actually looks like
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
because the element of $M_{2\times 2}$ that has a single 1 in the top left corner and otherwise all zeroes is expanded as
$$
1\cdot \vec e_1 + 0\cdot \vec e_2 + 0\cdot \vec e_3 + 0\cdot \vec e_4
$$
where the $\vec e_i$ are the basis vectors of $M_{2\times 2}$. And it is these four coefficients that conventional linear algebra notation is made to work on, so it is these four coefficients we put into a column vector. The basis vectors are left implied. The fact that the basis vectors happen to be $2\times 2$ tables of numbers is not really relevant at this stage. You have it in the back of your mind when you do your calculations, but it doesn't really appear in the standard notation.

The expansion of $T(\vec e_1)$ into a single column follows the same reasoning.

Thus the first column of the matrix representation of the linear transformation should be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\-3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The exact form of the other columns will depend on how you order your basis vectors, so I leave those to you.

Comment: Amazing explanation, feel like I'm starting to understand!